# Show and Hide text in HTML email Template

Tags: email

I am trying to show and hide the text using style attribute of html, but it is not hiding the text.

**`<p style="display:{!IF(Task.Description!='',' ','none')}">  Regarding {!Task.Description}, </p>`**

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might not be using VisualForce email templates.

Try `CASE` tags instead of `IF` tag and it should work.

`{!CASE(Task.Description, "", " ", "none")}`